# How to swipe views randomly

Tags: ios, swift, random, uiview

[image]

In my `viewController` I have 6 views.
The top views are source view and bottom views are destination views.
I want to add randomizer on source view as well as on destination view.
I want to change position of view randomly. So please give me any solution to do this.
I want to swipe position randomly of source view and destination view.
below is my code...

```
@IBOutlet weak var circle_source: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var circle_destination: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var square_source: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var square_destination: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var triangle_source: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var triangle_destination: UIView!
```

Comment: make it more clear what swipe you want?

Comment: I want to swipe position randomly of source view and destination view. Top views are source view and bottom views are destination view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var circle_source: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var circle_destination: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var square_source: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var square_destination: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var triangle_source: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var triangle_destination: UIView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let allViews = [circle_source, circle_destination, square_source, square_destination, triangle_source, triangle_destination].compactMap { $0 }
        let positions = allViews.map { $0.frame.origin }.shuffled() // randomize all posible positions
        positions.enumerated().forEach { (index, position) in
            allViews[index].frame.origin = position
        }
    }
}

extension Array {
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var results = [Element]()
        var indexes = (0 ..< count).map { $0 }
        while indexes.count > 0 {
            let indexOfIndexes = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
            let index = indexes[indexOfIndexes]
            results.append(self[index])
            indexes.remove(at: indexOfIndexes)
        }
        return results
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to change views like as swipe

Comment: @VikasDhasal for example you want circle_source and circle_destination to swap positions randomly?

Comment: No. for example i want to swipe on source circle on source triangle position also like as square  destination on triangle destination like as randomly....I want views change position and go to others view position and other view acquire positions randomly

Comment: @VikasDhasal ok one minute

Comment: @VikasDhasal i have updated the answer, does it help?